# How to make Git notice the filenames' capitalization changes for the commit?

Tags: windows, git, rename, case-sensitive, file-rename

I changed all filenames in a folder to lowercase (in Windows CDM as [here](https://superuser.com/a/412413/194560) explained):

```
$ D:\
$ cd my\folder
$ for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%f" "%f")
```

Now I expected `git status` to display me the changes, that I could `add` & `commit`. But Git seems to ignore these renamings.

As workaround I can e.g. rename the folder, `commit` it, rename it back and `commit` it again. Or something like this. But I'd like to find a "healthy" solution.

I also don't want to rename with `git mv`. So what I'm looking for is, how to (rename with OS tools and then) `commit` the filename (case) changes.

**Is there a way / How to `commit` case changes in filenames, after the changes have already been made (means: without [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv#git-mv--f))?** (Perhaps with some Git configurations?)

Comment: @CodeCaster It's not a duplicate, since the it's about another situation: after the renaming.

Comment: @Chris It's not a duplicate, since the it's about another situation: after the renaming.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did. Once again: I want to resolve this without `git mv`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Already tried that (` git config --global core.ignorecase false`). No effect.

Comment: No, you should edit your repo's config. Repo configs override global configs. Your repo's config has it set to `true`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Just tried `git config --local core.ignorecase false` -- it works. Feel free to post it as answer, I will `accept` it.

Comment: Meh, just accept the duplicate and I'll be happy. :) Your phrasing will help others find this question, which will then be linked to that duplicate.